# Change Realm file without restarting application

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm currently using dropbox to backup the Realm database file and when i need to restore, i just delete the old file and than put the new one from dropbox in its place, but to work i need to restart the application.
So, i'm looking a way to avoid the app restart.

Comment: Hey Kevin !! were you able to solve this buddy ?

Comment: Hey @Mr.Bean , I couldn't solve this buddy. I have tried so many ways and i have went though the realm document but this wouldn't be possible without restarting app.

Answer (score -1):

You could delete the current files the way Realm suggests in the docs: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#deleting-realm-files

Then nil your current Realm, write the new file to the right location in your file system and create a new Realm instance. Then reload your UI to show the new data.

You'll also have to be careful that your code is not holding references to objects in the previous Realm before it gets deleted.

Comment: Could you please suggest me how to nil current realm as it's giving an error, also please suggest me how to remove all the references to objects. Thanks! @Manuel

Comment: Nil cannot be assigned to type 'Realm' @Manuel

Comment: Is this a non-optional property in Swift? By niling it I simply meant dropping the reference so it would get deallocated, so you could make the property have type 'Realm?', or maybe just assign a new instance to it so the previous one goes away --just be careful that you do get a new instance, if you're using the default Realm configuration I can imagine it returning the same one. As for removing all references to Realm objects you would also make them optional, and when the time comes to reset your Realm stack then make sure they all become nil before you actually delete the Realm files.

Comment: Yes, it's non-optional property in swift. And assigning a new instance to it won't work. So, i just wanted to know that how to reset Realm stack or remove all references to Realm objects and make sure they all become nil. @Manuel